# SQL join with nullable columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join, null

I am trying to figure out what's the best approach, performance-wise, to joining two tables where one of the join columns may be null.

```
table1:
L_ID
U_ID
L_NAME
U_NAME

table2:
L_ID
U_ID
L_TAGS
```

This is on Oracle 11+, and in both the tables above, U_ID could be null. If it is null in one, it would be null in the other, fwiw.

I am currently using:

```
table1.L_ID = table2.L_ID
and nvl(table1.U_ID, 0) = nvl(table2.U_ID, 0)
```

Something tells me there may be a better way to make this work. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Make it [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so that index can be used if available.

```
where table1.L_ID = table2.L_ID
    and (
        table1.U_ID = table2.U_ID
        or (table1.U_ID is null and table2.U_ID is null )
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, appreciate it.

Comment: For this to make a difference there would need to be a compound index on `table1(l_id, u_id)` (or same columns indexed on `table2`, depending on the rest of the query.